# Why is it necessary to grant access to PostgreSQL sequences?

Tags: postgresql

Using PostgreSQL I see that the `pg_dump` command (and probably other commands) requires access to 'sequences'. I understand these to just be incremental IDs that are necessary for row identification...

Why is it necessary for server roles to be granted access to sequence objects? What are the potential security problems if every role had access to all sequences of accessible schemas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pg_dump` needs to dump the current position of the sequence, so that it can be restored. Otherwise, the restored sequence would start at 1 (or whatever its start value is) again and would generate duplicate keys.

Granting `SELECT` on the sequence should be enough for that purpose. Then the user can see the current value, but cannot increase or reset the sequence.

Comment: Do other database servers hide this from users by default? I guess that this prevents users from knowing how many rows are in a table unless they are explicitly allowed to know this?

Comment: The sequence value doesn't say much about the table row count.

Comment: Why not? I would have thought that an auto increment ID would use a sequence, and that the sequence current value would give a minimum row count of a table... 

What is the reason that Postgres prevents reading the sequence value by default? I can't imagine it being useful in any way from a security perspective (unless there is some reason that knowing a sequence value is a security compromise)

Comment: There are things like `DELETE` and `ROLLBACK` which make that sequence values used in an autoincrement column are not in the table. Also, sequences can cycle and be reset. It is a design principle (although some objects, like databases, functions and types, violate it) that after an object is created, the owner has all rights, and everybody else has no rights. Makes sense, doesn't it?

Comment: ... No it doesn't make sense that an object that has no bearing on security is associated with security roles. Especially since other objects such as databases, function, types, as you mention already violate the design principle that all objects are associated with security roles.

But that is just my opinion

Comment: Everybody is entitled to his own opinion, sure. The current behavior does not present a problem, though. And I am sure that there are people who would consider knowing a likely upper bound on the number of rows in a table a security problem.

Comment: True. Understanding the context just helps with reasoning about the software. Thank you